# I get an empty set when querying MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have this issue that drives me insane lately in which whenever I try to query the database I always get an empty result!

Please help and I am here for any more info or details.

This is the database class:

```
final class database
{

    private const DB_HOST     =   'localhost';
    private const DB_NAME     =   'branches';
    private const DB_CHARSET  =   'utf8';
    private const DB_USER     =   'public_user';
    private const DB_PASS     =   '1y37*V9ddGd@';
    public const EMAIL_TO    =   'someone@gmail.com';

    public static function database_connect()
    {
            // setting DSN (Data Source Name)
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::DB_HOST . ';' . 'charset=' . self::DB_CHARSET;

        try {

            // creating a PDO (PHP Data Object) instance
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASS);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $pdo;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            if (DEBUG === true) {

                echo "<pre><br><var>";
                print_r('An error has occured during database connection initiation Big Boss: <br> ' . $e);
                echo "</var></pre><br>";

            } else {

                $headers  = "From: admin@company.com" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: No One" . "\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

                if (mail(self::EMAIL_TO, 'An error has occured', $e, $headers)) {

                    echo 'المعذرة حدث خطاء فادح! لقد تم إرسال الخطاء إلى مطور الموقع لمعالجتة.';

                } else {

                    echo 'الرجاء التواصل مع مدير موقع شركة الجزيرة إخوان للصرافة على الإيميل التالي: <br>
                    someone@gmail.com';

                }

            }

        }

    }

    private function __clone() {}
}
```

and this is how I query the database from the index page:

```
    <?php
  $connection = Database::database_connect();
  $select_database = "use branches";
  Database::database_query($connection, $select_database);
                        $get_all_branches_query = "SELECT * FROM jazz_branches_ar WHERE branch_status = 1";
                        $query_results = Database::database_query($connection, $get_all_branches_query);
                        foreach ($query_results as $branch) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_fax'])))) , "</td>";
                                echo "<td><a class=\"inline-links\" href=\"tel:", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))), "\">", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))) ,"</a></td>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_address'])))), "</td>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_city'])))), "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

*Notes:*

- I am using shared hosting with GoDaddy.
- The old code used to work perfectly which I added below.

this is my old database class and as you could see it negites security measures of all kindes:

```
class Database
{
    private static $_db_host = 'mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8';
    private static $_db_user = 'jazz_god';
    private static $_db_pass = 'LcaQVNH3qz6Cksow';
    public static function database_connect() 
    {
        return $db_info = new PDO(Database::$_db_host, Database::$_db_user, Database::$_db_pass);
    }
    public static function database_query($db_connection, $query) 
    {
        $statment = $db_connection->prepare($query);
        $statment->execute();
        $result = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

and this is the code used to query the database:

```
<?php
                    $connection = Database::database_connect();
                    $select_database = $connection->prepare('use jazz_agents_branches');
                    $select_database->execute();
                    $get_all_branches_query = "SELECT * FROM jazz_branches_ar WHERE branch_status = 1";
                    $query_results = Database::database_query($connection, $get_all_branches_query);
                    foreach ($query_results as $branch) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_fax'])))) , "</td>";
                            echo "<td><a class=\"inline-links\" href=\"tel:", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))), "\">", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))) ,"</a></td>";
                            echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_address'])))), "</td>";
                            echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_city'])))), "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

And although I am putting my app at risk, I decided to include the list of libraries and php version I am using below:
[image: PHP version and Libraries]

Comment: Can you try with = :paramname on the statement and on the execute execute([':paramname' => 1"]) and print the sentence "$run_the_query->fetchAll()"

Comment: Hello, @UlyssesMarx thank you, but sadly no results!

Comment: Why is there a double quote after the one in your execute statement!!

Comment: @UlyssesMarx you should know that it works perfectly in localhost settings!

Comment: i tried your code and works fine, can you try this:
`$query_results = $run_the_query->fetchAll();
    var_dump($run_the_query->rowCount());exit;`

Comment: This is what I get int(0) @UlyssesMarx

Comment: It is so frustrating, I start to get very depressed!

Comment: So if the rowCount shows that can be tow things:
1.- Your table is empty
2.- The statememnt of the where doesn't match with any record

So if you are running the app copy the config values to connect via Shell to mysql to request the table.

Comment: Are you sure that the user have the permissions for access to that database and table?

Comment: @UlyssesMarx If I don't have the permission I always get an error, and the table is not empty I have 31 records, I have also tried the same statement inside PHPMyAdmin and it returned 28 records!

Comment: And I cannot access the Shell to MySQL since I am using a shared hosting plan.

Comment: So you don't have an own server?

Comment: If it is shared you need to check the IP for the Server on the Admin and give Allow Access Remote

Comment: I do not want to enable Remote Access due to the security headaches I get after doing that!

Comment: It seems that localhost actually doesn't get the correct connection, if you doesn't have an Exception of connection so the table is empty but if the sahred hosting have two diferente dns/ips so actually you can't access by localhost, PhpMyAdmin shows the localhost set by default by you provider.

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I have changed it to `localhost` due to some security concerns, in the shared hosting I use the domain name instead the `localhost` which in this case is `aljazeerabros.com`

Comment: So now you can read the table?

Comment: @UlyssesMarx Sadly no!

Comment: Oh Odin, Thor, Loki or whoever God is listening, I need help desperately!

Comment: Come on someone gotta help me!

Comment: Set on the PDO construct this :

` [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING]`

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I did and nothing happened!

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I already tried the following settings:

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',                1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',   1);
ini_set('html_errors',                    1);
ini_set('xmlrpc_errors',                1);`

Comment: on a side note do you think this code has something to do with it:

Comment: `define('CLASS_DIR', '../.includes/.classes/', false);

        set_include_path(CLASS_DIR);

        spl_autoload_extensions('.class.inc.php');

        spl_autoload_register();
`

Comment: who is your hosting shared provider?

Comment: @UlyssesMarx my shared hosting provider is GoDaddy!

Comment: Dear @UlyssesMarx I need a help so bad I have tried every play in my book and nothing worked and I do not want to go back to the old code!

Comment: Can you go to Web Hosting -> Manage for your domain and after tell me what PHP Version did you use and if you actually select "PDO" library?

Comment: `PHP version is 7.2`, `pdo` and `pdo_mysql` are enabled by default! –

Comment: Can you put the image of your configuration of the database on the admin panel? i dunno why i dont feel that localhost is right. even the port connection.

Comment: I do not understand what configuration you mean!!

Comment: @UlyssesMarx did you mean the real connection settings!?!

Comment: and I am not using `localhost` I am using `aljazeerabros.com` even though if there is an issue it should show me a connection error!

Comment: localhost vs your domain on godaddy i understand is different by the fact that if your wanna access by  aljazeerabros.com you need to enable your remote access and use the correct port to do it

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I have tried both of them and nothing really matters, here is the exact settings of the server:

Comment: These are the exact IP's I am allowed to connect to: `160.153.16.40`
`46.252.205.150`

Comment: which port did you use? is open?

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I do not use any port! I guess it uses the defaults!

Comment: check the port and the host configuration on godaddy panel

Comment: @UlyssesMarx there is no port specification which suggests that they are using the defaults: `3306`, moreover I do not see why this relates to my issue here.

Comment: i think that we have two options: 1.- The connection is never success and the exception never comes, if is the connection we need to be sure that the settings are correct, port, user, host, etc. 2.- Your GoDaddy isn't attempting to connect with that script (did you try the easy way to connect?).

Comment: @UlyssesMarx if the connection has failed I should get an `ErrorException`, and if you mean the easy way is `mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");`, then yes it works flawlessly!

Comment: So you have something wrong with your PHP Script.

Comment: Sounds stupid put try putting this, erase on $dns the `'dbname=' . self::DB_NAME . ';' ` and on your script put on the try `$connection = database::database_connect();
    $run_the_query_ = $connection->prepare('use branches');
    $run_the_query_->execute();`

Comment: @UlyssesMarx I get an error `An error has occured during database connection initiation Big Boss: 
 PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  in ....cls.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Web_OPS\htdocs\includes\.classes\database.class.inc.php(31): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=...', '...', '...')
#1 C:\Web_OPS\htdocs\aljazeerabros\index.php(128): database::database_connect()
#2 {main}`

Comment: can you update your script on the question to see your full code

Comment: @UlyssesMarx the code is still the same!

Comment: or you mean after I erase the `'dbname=' . self::DB_NAME . ';'`

Comment: you need to erase that part and add the code that i put

Answer (score 0):

Just put this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::DB_HOST . ';' . 'charset=' . self::DB_CHARSET;
```

and on the try:

```
 $connection = database::database_connect();
 $select_database = $connection->prepare('use branches');
 $select_database->execute();
```

Your code need to be:

```
    <?php
  $connection = Database::database_connect();
  $select_database = "use branches";
  Database::database_query($connection, $select_database);
                        $get_all_branches_query = "SELECT * FROM jazz_branches_ar WHERE branch_status = 1";
                        $query_results = Database::database_query($connection, $get_all_branches_query);
                        foreach ($query_results as $branch) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_fax'])))) , "</td>";
                                echo "<td><a class=\"inline-links\" href=\"tel:", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))), "\">", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_tel'])))) ,"</a></td>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_address'])))), "</td>";
                                echo "<td>", htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($branch['branch_city'])))), "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

And the email error on your class change email to public you can't access to a private property of a class:

```
public const EMAIL_TO    =   'someone@gmail.com';
```

Comment: now I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private const database::EMAIL_TO in /home/public/index.php:157 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/public/index.php on line 157`

Comment: and If I enable error_reporting this is what I get first: `An error has occured during database retrival Big Boss: PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in /home/public/index.php:134 Stack trace: #0 /home/public/index.php(134): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}`

Comment: Update your code on the stack question to see your full code

Comment: i still see "
            // setting DSN (Data Source Name)
            `$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::DB_HOST . ';' . 'dbname=' . self::DB_NAME . ';' . 'charset=' . self::DB_CHARSET;"`

Comment: You need to erase the "dbname" param and put this " $connection = database::database_connect();
 $select_database = $connection->prepare('use branches');
 $select_database->execute();"

Comment: nothing worked! the same error I had at the very start!

Comment: where did you put the "use database"? i didnt see it on your script

Comment: anyhow I just did.

Comment: did you trying creating another account or server?

Comment: I would love too, however, It would require me to pay more money!

Comment: Look im cto and i manage the infraestruture on my company, my advice is always use a good tech, like DigitalOcean, AWS, Vultr, even heroku, goodaddy is only for buy some domains and exist another pages even better, try to get a small server on DigitalOcean or Vultr and set your app there.

Comment: I appreciate the advise Mr. @Ulises, however, is it possible and if not too much to find someone who could fix this headache. I may lose my job!!

Comment: Send a support ticket to godaddy  maybe the server itself is with the wrong configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173241/discussion-between-hamzaabdullah-and-ulises).

Comment: There must be something wrong with how they handle Arabic because if only change the name of the table to `jazz_branches` it workes fine, however, I do not want the English results. @Ulises